# rendering issue when using autoSizePresetSizes in Textview

Tags: android, textview

I tried to use autosizing feature of textview. I just copied from google documentation but it not rendering the layout. There is an error of inflation.

my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="@string/title_home"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:autoSizePresetSizes="@array/autosize_text_sizes" />
</LinearLayout>
```

arrays.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="autosize_text_sizes">
        <item>10sp</item>
        <item>12sp</item>
        <item>20sp</item>
        <item>40sp</item>
        <item>100sp</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

Render Error

> Exception raised during rendering: Binary XML file line #-1: Error
>   inflating class  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException     at
>   android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.obtainTypedArray(Resources_Delegate.java:531)
>     at android.content.res.Resources.obtainTypedArray(Resources.java:615)
>     at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:1233)   at
>   android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:832)     at
>   android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:828)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
>     at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:166)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:225)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)  at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:325)
>     at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:384)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:547)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:681)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Note: the autosizing feature works perfectly without autoSizePresetSizes. i.e with mintextsize and maxtextsize. what's the workaround for this.
Using comiple and target sdk version 27.0.2, support library 27.0.2 and android studio 3.0.1. changed rendering api from best to 27 and 26 but not worked.

Comment: Can anyone reproduce this issue.